# Is this proof of an elementary formula for the second derivative correct?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, proof-verification

Let $f : (a,b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$  be twice continuously differentiable.

I want to rigorously show the well-known formula

$$f''(t) = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{h^2} ( f(t+h) + f(t-h) - 2f(t)).$$

So define the functions $\epsilon(t,h), \xi(t,h)$ by the following formulas:

$$ f'(t) = \frac{f(t+h)-f(t-h)}{2h} + \epsilon(t,h)$$

and

$$ f''(t) = \frac{f'(t+h)-f'(t-h)}{2h} + \xi(t,h).$$

By the properties of $f$, $\xi, \epsilon$ are continuous in $t$ for fixed nonzero $h$, and for fixed $t$ tend to $0$ as $h$ tends to $0$.

Applying these formulas we get

$$f''(t) = \frac{1}{2h} \left( \frac{f(t+2h)- f(t)}{2h} - \frac{f(t)- f(t-2h)}{2h}\right) + \frac{\epsilon(t+h,h) - \epsilon(t-h,h)}{2h},$$

and it's enough to show that the second term goes to $0$ with $h$.

But the second term equals $\epsilon'(t_0(h),h)=\xi(t_0(h),h)$ for some $t_0(h) \in [t-h,t+h]$ (the derivative is with respect to $t$ for fixed $h$) and looking at the definition of $\xi$ we see that $ \xi(t_0,h) = f''(t_0) - f''(t_1)$ for some $t_1(h) \in [t-2h,t+2h]$. Finally we see that

$$ |f''(t_0)-f''(t_1)| \leq \sup_{x,y \in [t-2h,t+2h]} |f''(x) - f''(y)| \rightarrow 0 \quad \textrm{as} \quad h \rightarrow 0. $$

I use the Mean Value theorem repeatedly above.

Is this argument rigorous?

Many thanks for helping me.

Comment: Such a thing as a $100$% rigorous argument does not exist.

Comment: Thanks for your help Ahmed...... I have edited the post accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f$ is twice continuously differentiable on $(a,b)$, the easiest *rigorous* proof is with l'Hôpital's theorem.
\begin{align}
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(t+h) + f(t-h) - 2f(t)}{h^2}
&=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f'(t+h)-f'(t-h)}{2h}\\
&=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f''(t+h)+f''(t-h)}{2}\\[6px]
&=f''(t)
\end{align}

I see no obvious error in your argument, though.

---

The hypothesis that the second derivative is continuous is redundant; just its existence is sufficient. This of course implies continuity of the (first) derivative. After the first application of l'Hôpital we can go on as
$$
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f'(t+h)-f'(t-h)}{2h}=
\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{1}{2}
\left(\frac{f'(t+h)-f'(t)}{h}+\frac{f'(t)-f'(t-h)}{h}\right)
$$
and this limit is just $f''(t)$, by applying the definition.

Comment: Thanks for this.  What I don't understand is that the second application of l'Hôpital seems a bit artificial. The expression on the RHS of the first line automatically equals $ f''(t) $ should this exist.  So I don't really see how the continuity of the second derivative is essential to your argiment.....?

Comment: (So I suppose I am asking, is continuity of the second derivative necessary and if so where do you use it...?)

Comment: @Frank Continuity of the second derivative is necessary for the final equality. On the other hand, as you observed, there is no need to apply l'Hôpital the second time, but as the hypotheses on $f$ allow to, why not?

Comment: Sure, I understand this,  what I mean is, if you didnt use l'Hôpital a second time but instead just wrote $=f''(t) $ straight after the first application, your argument would appear to adapt to the case with no continuity of the second derivative.  This suggests the result holds in the absence of this hypothesis.  So I am asking, is the result true without this hypothesis? Or am I misunderstanding something? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Frank You just need “twice differentiable”. I added the proof.

Comment: Yes that's what I thought. Bit confusing that my book writes twice continuously differentiable in the hypotheses! Many thanks for your help and patience.