# Where is the hypothesis of continuity of the second derivatives used in this simple lemma?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I am reading a book on complex analysis which contains this elementary lemma:

"Let $I$ be an open set in $\mathbb{R}$ and let$\phi$ be a twice continuously differentiable real-valued function on $I$. If there exists a $t_0 \in I$ such that $\phi(t) \leq \phi(t_0)$ for all $t \in I$ then $\phi''(t_0) \leq 0.$"

The proof presented goes as follows:

$$\phi''(t_0) = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{h^2}  (\phi(t_0 +h) + \phi(t_0-h) - 2\phi(t_0))  \leq 0 $$

where the inequality holds because the function in the limit is $\leq 0$ by the hypothesis.

So where is the contintuity of the second derivatives used? c.f. the answer to this post which shows that the forumla used for the second derivative in this one-line proof doesn't require this hypothesis:

[Is this proof of an elementary formula for the second derivative correct?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1201532/is-this-proof-of-an-elementary-formula-for-the-second-derivative-correct)

Many thanks for your help.